# Problem in use of vue-cookies in vue.js 3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-cookies

I have a problem, and it's that I'm trying to use Vue cookies, but I'm encountering this issue:

I have installed it using: `npm install vue-cookies`

in main.ts (TypeScript)

```js
import { VueCookies } from 'vue-cookies';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router).use(VueCookies, {expires: '1d'}).mount('#app');
```

but show this error.

[image]

[image]   this problem is showed!

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Particularly what the import statement looks like there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the import statement to:

```
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'
```

by following the [official docs](https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies#package-managers)